# Cannot connect to MySql database from Eclipse : java/sql/SQLException

Tags: mysql, eclipse, jdbc

I have set up a database with MySql.
I want to connect to it from Eclipse.

I followed the same steps as mentioned in this link:
https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/Setup_MySQL_DB_in_Eclipse

So I am using this library for the driver:
mysql-connector-java-5.1.45
whhich I think is correct

The name of my database is "test" and the port used by MySql is 3306.

This is my configuration:

[image]

But when I test the connection it's giving me an error message :
"An internal error occurred during: "Ping server job". java/sql/SQLException"

I have looked more in details in the error log and I see error like this:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/Connection

I have turned off my firewall just to check, but it does not solve the issue.

Can someone tell me what I should check?
Thanks

I use Java version 1.7.0_80 and Eclipse Mars.2 Release (4.5.2).

Comment: Your driver is not finding the proper jar. Search on a good tutorial on how to configure mysql access from Eclipse.

Comment: The error seems to suggest there is a problem with locating classes from `java.sql.*`, which in itself would suggest something is really broken. Which Java version and which Eclipse version are you using?

Comment: Are you trying to use Java 9?  Looks like there may be some special setup,/modules you need to add.  I've also seen paople having issues using Java 9 with the latest Eclipse

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I use Java version 1.7.0_80 and Eclipse Mars.2 Release (4.5.2).

Comment: @JGlass I use Java version 1.7.0_80 and Eclipse Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)

Comment: I agree with @Mark-Rotteveel, it does look like somethings seriously screwed up with your environment - any reaon your using Mars instead of something newer (though I agree AI dont upgrade often).  Have you tried this plug-in [DBViewer Plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/dbviewer-plugin) I wonder if it will work for you

Comment: @JGlass I gave up and used MysQL Workbench which meets my needs. Thanks for your inputs though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up and used MysQL Workbench which meets my needs.